# Trick SciPy into convolution for sparse diagonal systems

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to convert some code to Python but I noticed that SciPy's sparse diagonal operations are having some trouble handling systems that are diagonal.

For example the following code can be written as a per-pixel convolution, which in my C++ implementation is really fast. With overlap, it is approximately the memory access time. I would expect Python to know this because the system is diagonal.

When I try to run it in Python my terminal hogs the system resources and nearly  killed my system. For example, the Matlab version goes much faster.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
print(np.version.version)
color=imread('lena.png')
gray=mean(color,2)
[h,w]=gray.shape
img=gray.flatten()
ne=h*w;
L=np.ones(ne);
M=.5*np.ones(ne);
R=np.ones(ne);
Diags=[L,M,R]
mtx = sparse.spdiags(Diags, [-1,0,1], ne, ne);
#blured=np.dot(mtx,img) Dies
```

I understand I could rewrite it as 'for' loop going  through the pixels, but is there a way I can keep a sparse data structure while keeping performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mtx.dot` instead of `np.dot` as

```
blured = mtx.dot(img)
```

or just

```
blured = mtx * img # where mtx is sparse and img is `dense` or `sparse`
```

Two parameters of `np.dot` is dealt with `dense` even though one of them is `sparse`.
So, this will raise `MemoryError`